# Wiring a light fixture light will not turn off

Tags: wiring, lighting

I replaced a light fixture and everything worked fine until I tries to turn it off.  The overhead lights turned off like normal but the fixture stayed on.  I can’t figure out why this happened.  There are 3 white wires, 3 black wires, 3 brown wires and a black and white connected to each other.  I’m at a loss.[image][image] i connected everything the way it was when I removed the old fixture.  There is a fan and gfc? outlet that runs on the same fuse.[image]

Comment: Did you make some kind of record or note of how the old fixture was wired before you disconnected it?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the switch that controls this?

Comment: It would be super helpful if you labeled the pics to indicate before/after, as well as identifying the wiring in each. Right now, assuming the first pic is "after", it appears that _all_ wires are connected _all_ the time, which would, presumable, mean the light's on when the breaker's on and off when the breaker's off. _I_ don't see any indication of where a switch fits in there at all...

Comment: Nothing is after- these pics are the wiring without me touching anything.  Just removing the old vanity light and face plate.

Answer (score 1):

### Connect the fixture hot to white/black instead of black/black

What you have here is an old-school *switch loop* connection that's also feeding switched-hot onward to another set of fixtures.  When you initially hooked the fixture up, you connected the fixture's hot to the junction of the two black wires, which is where the incoming always-hot connects to the switch loop's always-hot.  This meant that the switch had no control over the fixture at that box, just the downstream fixture as you observed.  If you instead connect the fixture's hot to the junction of the white and black wires in that box, you'll be connecting it where the switched-hot returning from the switch connects to the downstream switched-hot, and thus will have everything working as you expect.

Comment: I connected the white to the 3 white and black to the 2 black and the ground to the green screw. I didn’t touch the one that has black and white together that’s why I’m so confused 

Comment: @thebeen -- switched my answer around for you :) (NEC 200.7(C)(1) says the white wire in an old-style switch loop's supposed to be the always-hot, not the switched-hot, but many installs predate that Code text I'm sure)

Comment: Thanks! Okay, I tried this black to switch loop and white to white.  Wrapped and capped the 2 black and did nothing with them.  Now when the light switch is off, the vanity light and 1 recessed light is on.  When the switch is on both recessed lights work and vanity light goes off.  No idea what I’ve done! might have gotten I over my head.

Comment: @thebeen -- no, cap the white and the black that were together back together and connect the fixture hot to the *combination* of those two wires